# How to use optim() for sqrt optimization

Tags: r

I don't get how to use the optim() function. I tried something simple (at least i thought so). Here is the code:

```
w<-c(0.5,0.5)
A<-runif(100)
B<-runif(100)
c<-function(w,A,B) sqrt(w[1]*A + w[2]*B)
optim(w,c)
Error in w[1]*A:'A' is missing
```

I have seen various questions of this type but I still don't know what is wrong. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things to look at in the code above.

First, in the `optim` function you need to pass in the other arguments to `c` (as part of the `...` argument to `optim`:

```
optim(w, c, A = A, B = B)
```

But that still won't run because the function your trying to optimise returns a vector (optim tries to minimise the value of the function by default).

Because you say it's an example, it's not clear what to do with the function `c` but just to show something that should work, you could try the sum of the squared differences between A & B:

```
c <- function(w, A, B) sum((w[1] * A - w[2] * B)^2)
optim(w, c, A = A, B = B)
```

Comment: how can I add multiple constraints (w can only vary in a certain range or w[1] can vary in a different range than w[2] or the sum of w[1...n]=x? I have looked at constrOptim but I only found a solution for upper and lower boundaries for the entire vector w.

Comment: Maybe try here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137734/r-optim-function-setting-constraints-for-individual-parameters